# Static Data to be displayed using XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I modify my XML now, I have a parent element `<imgRes>` in my XML in that I am having two different child nodes `<images>` and <`rightContent>`.

In earlier I wont have `<imgRes>` and `<rightContent>`, As i added it my code then its not adding in the div. I dont know whether my XML structure is wrong or something is missing.

So the <`rightContent>` having a div which is static which should be outside of the image sliding functionlity. I holds a link and a data.

I need some help where I am going wrong.

This is what I have tried.

http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you were never retrieving the data from the xml to set it into your new DOM elements. I updated the jsfiddle to alter the css and dom a bit so that the rightContent div wouldn't contain the link itself but the main piece you needed was this:

```
$("#rightContent").text( $xmldata.find('rightData').find('data').text());
$("#rightLink").prop('href',$xmldata.find('rightData').find('link').text());
prevIndex++;
```

The updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/14/) will show the minor changes.

If you want to update not only the URL of the link but also the link text then you can add something like this to set that value.

```
$("#rightLink").text($xmldata.find('rightData').find('link').text());
```

Note that the hardcoded values in the jsfiddle are just for demonstration. You can define whatever elements you like in the xml and then parse then into dom element values through jquery.

Comment: I need to show both the click here and the href link; Onclick of click here then it renders to that href link. XML should use for both the data, we should not hardcode it.

Comment: Click here it should visible to everyone, but onclick it should redirect to google.com, but this google.com and click here text should parse from xml only

Comment: Yes its working but the Click Here that you are hardcoding in the html should not be like that, It should also be in the XML and it should parse and get the value Click here from XML

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect setting the link text from the xml as well.

Comment: Yeah I got it thank you very much Here is the Updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/18/